# LSTM multi-step prediction in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I want to make the multi-step prediction using the RNN.

Example: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]` - full time-series. `X_train = [1...13]` as train, the rest X_test = [14...16] is test data. I check the performance of the model as

```
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

I receive the numbers (predictions) but they are for the past period? If I want to predict the next 6 points in the future. I will use

```
prediction = model.predict(X_input)
```

What I have to use for `X_input`? If I have already used the last observations as a testing performance of the model. All tutorials show how perfect the model work to predict the past but I need to use the model for future prediction. I will really appreciate any advice.

Comment: There are different ways to forecast the timeseries data Recursive strategy, direct strategy, multiple output strategy. Thanks!